# How to caption multiple sub-tables contained in one table environment

Tags: tables, align, captions, subcaption, alignment

So I have 4 tables side-by-side to each other, and I'd like to add a caption at the bottom to each one of them.
Whenever I try to add a caption it disrupts the alignment, and the tables go off to everywhere.

How could I go about solving this?

What I have so far:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ |c| }
        \hline
        Variety \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        bramsley\_seedling \\ 
        cox\_orange\_group \\ 
        egremont\_russet \\ 
        braeburn \\
        gala \\
        other\_early\_season \\
        other\_late\_season \\
        other\_mid\_season \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ |c| }  
        \hline
        Variety \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        conference \\ 
        doyenne\_du\_comice \\ 
        other \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ |c| }  
        \hline
        Variety \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        topped\_washed \\  
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ |c| }  
        \hline
        Variety \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        red \\ 
        savoy \\ 
        summer\_autumn\_pointed \\ 
        white \\
        round\_green\_other \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

This outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.22\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                     row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    bramsley\_seedling      \\
    cox\_orange\_group      \\
    egremont\_russet        \\
    braeburn                \\
    gala                    \\
    other\_early\_season    \\
    other\_late\_season     \\
    other\_mid\_season      \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{subtable}%
    \quad
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.22\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    conference              \\
    doyenne\_du\_comice     \\
    other                   \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{subtable}%
    \quad
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.2\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    topped\_washed          \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{subtable}%
    \quad
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.28\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    red                     \\
    savoy                   \\
    summer\_autumn\_pointed \\
    white                   \\
    round\_green\_other     \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                     row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    bramsley\_seedling      \\
    cox\_orange\_group      \\
    egremont\_russet        \\
    braeburn                \\
    gala                    \\
    other\_early\_season    \\
    other\_late\_season     \\
    other\_mid\_season      \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}%
    \quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    conference              \\
    doyenne\_du\_comice     \\
    other                   \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}%
    \quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    topped\_washed          \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}%
    \quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.28\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={c},
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
                    }
    Variety                 \\
    red                     \\
    savoy                   \\
    summer\_autumn\_pointed \\
    white                   \\
    round\_green\_other     \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, for tables is used `tabularray` package. BTW, you may consider left align of table body context. In this case the column specification in tables can be:

```
    \begin{tblr}[t]{hline{1,2,Z}={solid}, vlines,
                    colspec={l},
                    row{1}={c, font=\bfseries}
                    }
```

[image]